# Sharepoint 2010: Site Arrangement/Multiple sites as part of quick launch

Tags: 2010, site, quick-launch

I am having a Central site created. I am trying design the layout.  I want to be able have up to 15 individual site links displayed on the Quick Launch bar.

Is this possible? If so, how so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in two ways.

1: You can create site navigation and allow then for Quick lunch bar.
2: you can create Term Set for those sites and add then in Quick Lunch.

2nd option is best for you as you want central repository.

Comment: Ok, I see how to create Custom links on the quick launch.  For each of the 15 links I want four equal-level sub-sites to each of the main sites.    How can I do this?  For example: On Quick launch Site 1(MTIR) with four containers on equal level for proper routing of documents and so on for each remaining site.